# Iterating through json objects using php

Tags: php, sql, json, parsing, codeigniter-3

I currently have a json array of objects and would like to fetch only the status fields. I need to verify if the `status == 0`. If the status equals 0 then I would like for it to do something.

I would like to iterate through each object and grab the status value so that my the output depends on the value specified in each object. How can improve my code to iterate and grab the status column correctly for each object?

```
 [  
       {  
          "user_id":"1",
          "notification_id":"7",
          "id":"7",
          "product_id":"4233",
          "message":"2",
          "type":"2",
          "created_at":"1493618633",
          "status":"0"
       },
       {  
          "user_id":"1",
          "notification_id":"8",
          "id":"8",
          "product_id":"4233",
          "message":"4",
          "type":"0",
          "created_at":"1493618663",
          "status":"0"
       },
       {  
          "user_id":"1",
          "notification_id":"9",
          "id":"9",
          "product_id":"4232",
          "message":"45",
          "type":"1",
          "created_at":"1493618784",
          "status":"0"
       }
    ]
```

model

```
public function getNotifications($timestamp, $user_id){
        $sql =  "SELECT * FROM storelte_user_notifications LEFT JOIN storelte_notifications ON storelte_user_notifications.notification_id = storelte_notifications.id  WHERE created_at >= ? AND user_id = ? ORDER BY created_at";
        $response = $this->db->query($sql, array($timestamp, $user_id));
        return $response->result_array();
    }
```

How I tried to fetch data in my json

```
$array = $this->notification->getNotifications($timestamp, $user_id);
        if ($array > 0) {
            if (empty(array_filter(array_column($array, 'status'))) == 0) { 
                echo 'unread'; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you want test that **all status** are zero or not ?

Comment: extacly , but I want to output only one . one for all

Comment: `        if (empty(array_filter(array_column($array, 'status')))) {
            echo 'echo';
         } `

Comment: I get 3 times the same echo , but can I output just one

Comment: write that instead foreach without any loop

Comment: It's an array of objects​. Try with `$value->status`.

Comment: at the moment I want to valid if status is equal to 0 or 1 appers white screen

Comment: I want to check if all all status are zero say they are unread ,but If I have one item with status 1 then read , but show what item has unread or read status

Comment: I have read the question and understand what the author is asking. The previous wording was not quite clear and the question left out some very important tags. Hopefully the improvement will help the author solve his/her issue.